# Limit CPU when starting a task in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, cpu

I'm working on an application for part of a school project that simulates an operating system and which I launch using the Terminal.  By nature it will consume all possible resources to loop over and over.  Is there a command or flag I can enter in Terminal to limit the amount of CPU it can utilize while it is running?  I tried using the following command:

```
$ nice -n 20 ./a.out
```

to set the priority as low as possible, but it still took up 100% CPU to run.  It's a rather simple program and hardly needs any resources to work properly so any limits imposed on it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

As nice only gives priority over over applications it won't stop 100% CPU usage.

Cputhrottle has worked for me in the past, though haven't checked it for 10.11 : http://www.willnolan.com/cputhrottle/cputhrottle.html

Comment: Will cputhrottle work if I often start and stop the process?  I'll be debugging it so the process number will change often when it gets restarted.